# enabling javascript in Chrome using an AppleScript

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

Is it possible to enable Javascript in Chrome aside from manually scrolling through the View menu?  I tried scripting it, but it didn't execute or list any errors:

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Google Chrome"

        select menu item "Allow JavaScript from Apple Events" of menu 1 of menu item "Developer" of menu 1 of menu bar item "View" of menu bar 1

    end tell

end tell
```

Comment: I originally posted an **AppleScript** answer that went thru the steps of clicking the _menu items_, however, after the fact I found out that it didn't actually check/uncheck the _menu item_, so I've deleted it for now because it appears that only a physical click actually toggles the state of the _check_ on that _menu item_. I did find the setting for it in its preferences file but **Google Chrome** needs to be closed to programmatically edit the file. What exactly are you trying to do? Toggle the state of that _menu item_ each way or only toggle it depending if it's e.g unchecked?

Comment: Thanks.  I want to create an AppleScript to automatically set the homepage.  I had tried to set it by modifying the plist in ~/Library/Preferences but it didn't change the homepage, so I am looking to set it with an AppleScript, which worked for me when setting the default homepage in Safari.

Comment: Also, in answer to your question, I would be toggling on javascript to make the change, and then toggling it off when complete.